# If checkbox is checked, pop up a fancybox with HTML content from a Registration Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If checkbox is checked, pop up a fancybox with HTML content from a Registration Page

My current JS code is below. The alert is basically a placeholder for the HTML I want to grab & display.

```
$("#Register").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("This is a fancybox! Register here.")
        $('#CheckoutOptions').fancybox('');
    }
})
```

HTML code is:

```
<form id="CheckoutOptions" name="CheckoutOptions">
    <label class="inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Register" name="CheckoutOptions" value="Register">
     Register Account </label>
     <br>
    <label class="inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Guest" name="CheckoutOptions" value="Guest">
    Guest Checkout </label>
</form>
```

Inside of the HTML will be a form that the user can simply register an account. At the end of registering an account, if successful, I'd also like to close the Fancybox & reload the original web page.

Is that something you'd be able to help me with as well?

JSfiddle is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CS4D/3/

Comment: You forgot to add `fancybox` plugin in fiddle.and where is `#CheckoutOption`

Comment: You have most of the code done...I'm not too familiar with fancybox, but don't you just wrap your form in a container then call the plugin?

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` - really? this can be done so much easier: `this.checked` or if you - for whatever reason - prefer to use a jquery function: `$(this).prop('checked')` (but really, use `this.checked` as that's the fastest and cleanest way)

Comment: Updated jsFiddle & Showed my form #CheckoutOptions

Answer (score 0):

Please see the attached link here:- It is same as exactly you want:-

[Open Link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

You can be find out the source code along with the example.

You can also try following link:-
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Comment: Good answer, but I'd rather not use jQuery UI - I am using enough JS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle isn't including the js correctly. Also, you need to tell fancybox what you want to display.  I just put the form html in a string, but you can get it however you want to.

```
$("#Register").click(function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         var htmlStr = '<div class="form"><form>First Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input><br />Last Name:<input type="text" maxlength="20"></input></form></div>';
         $.fancybox(htmlStr, {
             'width': 950,
             'height': 1100,
             'autoScale': false,
             'transitionIn': 'none',
             'transitionOut': 'none',
             'hideOnContentClick': false
         });
     }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpauz/